# Tab bar image icon doesn't appear

Tags: objective-c, image, xcode4, uitabbar

I added a tabbar icon with a size of 32 by 32 pixels.

Here's my code:

```
self.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc]
                   initWithTitle:@"קווים" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"32*32.jpg"] tag:0];
```

But all I see is a blue color...

Here's the image I tried to show:

[image: The image I tried to show]

Comment: What language are you using?  What component?  How are you setting the image?  We can't see your image attachment.

Comment: @Brad: The post was edited, so I went and fixed it. The image is now visible.

Answer (score 5):

Your image doesn't seem to have any transparency. `UITabBarItem` only uses the alpha channel of an image, so any completely opaque image will simply appear as a solid square.

Answer (score 2):

UITabBar does its own rendering of the gray gradient and blue gloss. All you need to supply it is a transparent PNG—it doesn’t need any shading; it can just be a solid color—with its alpha channel providing a mask in the shape of your icon.

Answer (score 0):

Tab bars use the alpha mask of an image, so you need to do the outline of your icon, against a transparent background.